# Extract email address from inside 100's of text files

Tags: c#, full-text-search

My SMTP server got 100's of errors when sending lots of emails. Now have lots of .BAD files each one containing an error message and somewhere in the middle, the actual email address it was supposed to be sent to.

What is the easiest way to extract from each file "just" the "email address", so that I can have a list of the actual failed emails?

I can code in C# and any suggestion will be truly welcomed.

### BAD sample text:

```
From: postmaster@my.server.com
To: me@me.com
Date: Tue, 25 Sep 2012 12:12:09 -0700
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
    boundary="9B095B5ADSN=_01CD9B35032DF58000000066my.server.co"
X-DSNContext: 7ce717b1 - 1386 - 00000002 - C00402D1
Message-ID: <FRaqbC8wS00000068@my.server.com>
Subject: Delivery Status Notification (Failure)

This is a MIME-formatted message.  
Portions of this message may be unreadable without a MIME-capable mail program.

--9B095B5ADSN=_01CD9B35032DF58000000066my.server.co
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=unicode-1-1-utf-7

This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification.

Unable to deliver message to the following recipients, due to being unable to connect successfully to the destination mail server.

       email@stackoverflow.com




--9B095B5ADSN=_01CD9B35032DF58000000066my.server.com
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns;my.server.com
Received-From-MTA: dns;Social
Arrival-Date: Tue, 25 Sep 2012 11:45:15 -0700

Final-Recipient: rfc822;email@stackoverflow.com
Action: failed
Status: 4.4.7

--9B095B5ADSN=_01CD9B35032DF58000000066my.server.com
Content-Type: message/rfc822

Received: from Social ([127.0.0.1]) by my.server.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.17514);
     Tue, 25 Sep 2012 11:45:15 -0700
```

Mainly I want to find the `email@stackoverflow.com` email right in the middle.

Comment: nothing really...to be honest. I just got the files and wondered if anybody had any workable idea.

Comment: Are there more information in these .bad-files (such as the message that wasn't delivered?) that you don't want to search? A regular expression is probably the best way to go as long as you specify it clearly enough that it won't match extra addresses in the body or the error message.

Comment: based on the e-mail format in your file you can use regular expressions, if can tell us how exactly it's formatted it will be alot easier, and by format i mean for exmple <EmailAdress> , [EmailAdress] , TO: EmailAdress something like this.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren +1 regex is absolutely the correct way to go, especially when combined with grep.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need C# for this task, this can be solved much more simply with [Grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep). By writing a new C# program you're creating a new solution to a problem that was solved 40 years ago :)

Grep is a command line tool specifically designed to solve problems like this. It searches through a list of files matching a [glob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) (eg `*.bad`) and finds regular expression matches. You could then have it export all of those matches to a text file.

[This regular expression](http://regexr.com?32ala) should suffice for matching your email addresses:

```
(?<=^Final-Recipient: rfc822;)(.*)$
```

The grep command would be something like this:

```
grep "(?<=^Final-Recipient: rfc822;)(.*)$" *.bad >> emails.txt
```

This will put all the matched email addresses in a file named `emails.txt`.

You can get a windows version of Grep >[here](http://www.wingrep.com/)<, or windows has a built in alternative to grep called [findstr](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx) which may also match your needs.

edit: if you do decide to go down the `grep` route, you might want to ask this question again on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/). The SysAdmins there have a lot more expertise with this sort of thing than the developers on StackOverflow do :)

Answer (score 0):

I have one solution.... first you have to find the index of (To:) then use regular expression shown in below

```
      start = emailbody.IndexOf("To:");

                        if (start < 0)
                            start = 0;


     string emailExpression = @"([a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,3})";
      System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regExp = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(emailExpression);

                        if (regExp.IsMatch(eamilbody, start))

               {
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match = regExp.Match(emailbody, start);
                            string email = match.Value;

                 }
```

Comment: it's NOT the TO:me@me.com that i need, but the one in the middle "email@stackoverflow.com" ...that each text file will carry a different email address.